# How I can get last 5 days totals with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like:

```
id   answers  date    
12   A1       9-nov  
13   A2       10-nov 
14   A3       7-nov  
...
```

Now I want to calculate the total answer of last 5 days for each answers `A1`, `A2`, `A3`.

The output should be like:

```
answer  count(answer) 
A1      20 
A2      0
A3      34
```

How can I do that with MySQL?

Comment: What's the type of the date column?

Comment: thank you for your reply. its timestamp .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
SELECT answers, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`) >= 5
GROUP BY answers;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea806/1)

**Update:** Try this instead:

```
SELECT t1.answers, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.answers), 0)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT answers FROM table1
) t2 ON  t1.answers = t2.answers AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.`date`) <= 5
GROUP BY t1.answers;
```

### [SQL fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c25a/1)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but its not working suppose count of a2 is zero in those 5 days.

Comment: i think something problem was there with date DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.`date`) >= 5 please check. actually i have only 5 4 6 per each for last 5 days. but the answer was 54 55 23.

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi - Sorry it is ` DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.`date`) <= 5` instead of ` DATEDIFF(NOW(), t1.`date`) >= 5` See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the last 5 days? do you mean the last 5 days since now, or the last 5 days present in your table? If you mean the last 5 days present in your table, which can be more than 5 days ago if you miss some days in your table, then you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  ans.answers, count(last_tab.id)
FROM
  (select distinct answers from tab) ans
  left join
  (select id, answers
   from tabs
        inner join
        (select distinct date from tab order by date desc limit 5) dt
  on tab.date = dt.date) last_tab
  on ans.answers = last_tab.answers
group by ans.answers;
```